# Why can I get organisations from the CRM4 discovery service but not run requests against them?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I'm using the Microsoft CRM 4.0 SDK to connect to an Internet Facing Deployment (IFD). I can call the discovery service and get back a list of organisations. When I try to use one of the organisations, I get 401 Unauthorized errors. I've tried to boil it down to the simplest program possible to demonstrate this. The code (with URLs, user names and passwords changed) is shown below. I expect this to output the number of accounts in the organization. WhenI run it, I get a 401 Unauthorised exception at the point of using the service.

```
// Get orgs from disco service
CrmDiscoveryService disco = new CrmDiscoveryService();
disco.Url = "https://notthereal.crmurl.com/MSCRMServices/2007/SPLA/CrmDiscoveryService.asmx";
RetrieveOrganizationsRequest orgRequest = new RetrieveOrganizationsRequest();
orgRequest.UserId = @"mydomain\myuser";
orgRequest.Password = "mypassword";
RetrieveOrganizationsResponse orgResponse =
    (RetrieveOrganizationsResponse)disco.Execute(orgRequest);

// Find the test org
OrganizationDetail orgInfo = null;
foreach (OrganizationDetail orgdetail in orgResponse.OrganizationDetails)
{
    if (orgdetail.OrganizationName.Equals("TestOrganization"))
    {
        orgInfo = orgdetail;
        break;
    }
}
if (orgInfo == null)
{
    throw new Exception("The specified organization was not found.");
}

// Get a CRM ticket
RetrieveCrmTicketRequest ticketRequest = new RetrieveCrmTicketRequest();
ticketRequest.OrganizationName = orgInfo.OrganizationName;
ticketRequest.UserId = @"mydomain\myuser";
ticketRequest.Password = "mypassword";
RetrieveCrmTicketResponse ticketResponse
    = (RetrieveCrmTicketResponse)disco.Execute(ticketRequest);

// Create an authorization token
CrmAuthenticationToken sdktoken = new CrmAuthenticationToken();
sdktoken.AuthenticationType = 2;
sdktoken.OrganizationName = orgInfo.OrganizationName;
sdktoken.CrmTicket = ticketResponse.CrmTicket;
CrmService service = new CrmService();
service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = sdktoken;
service.Url = orgInfo.CrmServiceUrl;

// Retrieve the accounts
RetrieveMultipleRequest request = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();
request.Query = new QueryExpression("account");

// 401 EXCEPTION WHEN EXECUTING NEXT LINE
var response = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)service.Execute(request);

// Show the count of accounts
Console.WriteLine(response.BusinessEntityCollection.BusinessEntities.Count);
```

It seems strange to me that the disco service requests work correctly but the CRM service request blows up.

Comment: what is your account's access mode in CRM? is it ReadOnly?

Comment: Did you cam to know what was the error. I am experiencing the same error but on the first discovery service call...

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer for others as I experienced the same problem...

It looks like Richard has put the wrong value for AuthenticationType

```
CrmAuthenticationToken sdktoken = new CrmAuthenticationToken();
sdktoken.AuthenticationType = 2;
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb955408.aspx)

```
The AuthenticationType class exposes the following members. 
Field       Value   Description 
AD          0       Specifies Active Directory authentication. 
Passport    1       Specifies Windows Live ID authentication. 
Spla        2       Specifies Internet-Facing Deployment authentication (formerly known as SPLA).
```

This `AuthenticationType` enum can be used by adding a reference to `Microsoft.Crm.sdk.dll` as mentioned [here in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928920.aspx)